# Use PowerShell to Create a List of All Projects on a CCNet Server

Tags: powershell, cruisecontrol.net

I have been tasked with auditing build servers using CruiseControl.NET. There are quite a few of them, and I was wondering if there was a way to programmatically / automagically compile a list of the projects on each of them.

Is there a way to do this?

My first instinct is to use PowerShell (v2.0), but I am not sure how to begin writing a script that does what I require. Should I be using PowerShell, or some other method? What would those other methods be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the ccnet.config files, you can just:

```
([xml](Get-Content ccnet.config)).cruisecontrol.project | Select name, artifactDirectory # or whatever
```

Comment: Thank you! I will provide my PowerShell script for this kind of functionality in a minute.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the Thoughtworks.CruiseControl.Remote.dll and load it into powershell

Create `ICruiseManagerFactory managerFactory;`

and then you could iterate through a list of servers you have and Create the Uri for the server like:

```
 ServerUri = @"tcp://" + Server + ":" + Port + @"/CruiseManager.rem"
```

then get the list of Projects and statuses from that server using:

```
 ProjectStatus[] currentStatuses = managerFactory.GetCruiseManager(ServerUri).GetProjectStatus();
```

then iterate through the list:

```
        foreach (ProjectStatus projectStatus in currentStatuses)
        {
            string name = projectStatus.Name;
            string status = projectStatus.Status;
  }
```

Comment: That's interesting. It does seem like too much effort throwing relatively large objects around when one can achieve the same result using just one XML object. +1 for the alternative method, though! (when I earn enough reputation to upvote, that is ...)

Comment: The difference in the methods though is that my code can run from anywhere against any number of servers without having any needed permissions on the server, and without needing to access its file system :)

Comment: Yeah, I like that.  You should write a CruiseControl module ;)

Answer (score 2):

Powershell can read xml files really easily. You should use this to interrogate the CC.NET builds.

Start [here](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/12/30/processing-xml-with-powershell.aspx)  and [here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/30/chapter-14-xml.aspx)

Comment: Here is the code I'm using to load the XML: $xml = [xml](Get-Content ccnet.config). However, all it returns is the <cruisecontrol> root element. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong. That root element will have properties on it for each child element -- or you can use xpath. The documents Preet linked to are good starting points.

Comment: D'oh! Indeed, those blog posts do explain how to access child nodes / elements - I should have read all the way through. +1 for providing the useful links (when I earn enough reputation to upvote, that is ...).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their answers. :-) One thing I failed to mention is that all of the build servers have the same installation structure for CruiseControl.NET on them, and the installation directory is directly accessible through a folder share.

Putting it all together, here is my script for creating a list of projects on a particular build server:

```bsh
function Get-Projects
{
  param([string]$BuildServer = $(Throw "You must specify the name of the build server containing the projects you want to list"))
  $BuildServer = $BuildServer.ToUpper()

  $ConfigFilePath = [string]"\\$BuildServer\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.config"
  $ValidPath = Test-Path -Path "$ConfigFilePath"
  if (!$ValidPath)
  {
    $InvalidPathErrorMessage = [string]"Path $ConfigFilePath does not exist!"
    Write-Host $InvalidPathErrorMessage
    $InvalidPathErrorMessage
    return
  }

  $ConfigXml = [xml](Get-Content $ConfigFilePath)
  $Projects = @($ConfigXml.SelectNodes("cruisecontrol/project"))

  if (!$Projects)
  {
    $ErrorMessage = [string]"No projects on $BuildServer!"
    Write-Host $ErrorMessage
    $ErrorMessage
    return
  }

  $Projects
}
```

Then, assuming this script is accessible within your PowerShell session, you can simply select the data you want, as Jaykul suggested:

`Get-Projects <BuildServer> | Select-Object name, queue, category | Sort-Object category`

I hope this is found to be helpful!